# Is it legal to prevent customers from leaving gym class early?

Tags: criminal-law

The following directive was issued to class participants:

You may not leave class early. If you attend class you must stay for the entire class (unless there is an emergency).  There are NO EXCEPTIONS to these rules.  Instructors are aware and will be monitoring and enforcing these rules effective immediately.

This appears to be threatening and unlawful imprisonment and restraint!

Comment: How does the gym "justify" its directive? and what exactly does "enforcement" of that directive entail? i.e., what would be the punishment(s) for contravening the gym's nonsense?

Comment: There might be valid reasons such as *protecting each class from any other class to prevent the spread of Corona* but we need some more context

Comment: Iñaki is right: We need to know more about exactly what happens if you try to leave early. If they physically prevent or restrain you, then you might have a case. But if they simply say you'll be dropped from the class, then at most you might have a case for breach of contract.

Comment: It isn't clear to me, is this a commercial gym (where you sign up for a membership), or is this a school such that a minor would be in (Grade/Middle/High)? What country is this taking place in?

Comment: It seems possible this is not a new rule. Many classes require people to stay for an entire class to prevent disruption and distractions. Perhaps so many people were leaving that instructors found it disruptive. Or maybe others in the class complained.

Comment: This is a commercial establishment with various time lengths of membership.

Comment: The room has two doors and no one transverses through. There is no indication what the enforcement would be. This is in the US. This is new rule. 
Masks are worn entering to reach set work out area abd upon departing.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on where you live, but "restrain" doesn't mean telling a person that they have to stay put, it implies either a physical blockage (locking the door) or a threat of force, and neither of those are present or suggested by the sign. We don't know what the consequences are, for example they might report you to your parents or even restrain you if you are a minor (that's who is in most "gym classes"). If you are an adult, the consequence could be some contractual sanction (read the contract) or termination of the contract for breach (read the contract). You can simply ask a supervisor how they intend to enforce this restriction.

Comment: Ditto for "unlawful" imprisonment.